# add days on CURDATE() function in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to add days to the current date function in PHP but I'm not really sure how. Below is my code..

```
function due(){
    $it=$_POST['item_name'];
    $ab="select duration from item where item_name='$it'";
    $cd=mysql_query($ab);

    while($mn=mysql_fetch_array($cd)) {
        $interval=$_POST['duration'];
        $due='DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL'.$interval.'DAYS )';

        $gh=$_POST['request_name'];
        $ij=$_POST['requestid'];
        $ef="insert into request (due_date) values ('$due') where request_name='$gh' && requestid='$ij'";
        $kl=mysql_query($ef);
    }
}
```

DURATION is the number of days I would like to add to the current date

*** I'll elaborate my question further

DURATION is inserted into a table (TBL_A)
CURDATE() value is inserted in another table (TBL_B)

I would use the FUNCTION DUE() to select DURATION and add to the CURDATE() as DUE_DATE
DUE_DATE is inserted into TBL_B

DURATION varies on the item_name in TBL_A

DUE_DATE is selected in another program

Comment: did you try `DAY` instead of `DAYS`? you also fortgot a white space after `INTERVAL` and before `DAYS`. post your mysql error you get please. `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: This also looks vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: I've changed DAYS to DAY and added the white spaces before it and INTERVAL, also, no error is showing, I've added 'or die ($ef).mysql_error()' the result id just 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

You use  `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL X DAY)`  (not DAYS)

*from the MYSQL reference website. Check the docs!

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna do it using php, the simplest way is to use mktime

mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, int $month = date("n") [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )

it will be osmething like date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,date('m'), date('j')+$neededamountofdays), date('Y'));